# How to place the checkbox of a QCheckBox widget on the right, and text left-justified

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qcheckbox

Does Qt offer a way to configure the layout of a QCheckBox with Qt Stylesheets so that the text remains aligned to the right but the checkbox is placed on the far right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QCheckBox::setLayoutDirection(Qt::LayoutDirection direction)`:

```
auto chkB = new QCheckBox("some example");
 chkB->setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
```